# Aspnet RowDataBound Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In my gridview I have a column returning a value that can be either 0 or 1 or 2.

' />

I want to change the value of the colum by "NO', "YES" and "N/S" when the row value in the cell is respectively 0 or 1 or 2. I have been using that code below but my gridview only return the first row. Where the problem is hiding?

```
Sub GridPurch_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridPurch.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
    Dim myVal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(0).Text)
        If myVal = 0 Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "NO"
        ElseIf myVal = 1 Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "YES"
        ElseIf myVal = 2 Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "NS"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the change i made as advised but it returns only two rows out of three and the text in the cell does not change it still show the numeric value??

```
Sub GridPurch_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridPurch.RowDataBound
If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridPurch.Rows
        Dim myVal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(13).Text)
        If myVal = 0 Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "NO"
        ElseIf myVal = 1 Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "YES"
        ElseIf myVal = 2 Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "NS"
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, after your data loads into the data grid:
Get your program to change your values from the numbers to words

For Each row As DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.rows
     
Next

This code given should give you an idea of what to do and what to look for, just edit it to fit what you are trying to do. (google it for more help)

Comment: I did as advised but now can only see two rows out of three rows??

Comment: and the values do not change

Comment: Did you remember to change it in accordance to your code?